# Show that $\lim \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{(2n)!}=0$

Tags: limits

I have to show that $\lim \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{(2n)!}=0$

---

I am not sure if correct but i did it like this :
$(2n)!=(2n)\cdot(2n-1)\cdot(2n-2)\cdot ...\cdot(2n-(n-1))\cdot (n!)$ so I have $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{(2n)\cdot(2n-1)\cdot(2n-2)\cdot ...\cdot(2n-(n-1))}$$ and $$\lim \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(2n)\cdot(2n-1)\cdot(2n-2)\cdot ...\cdot(2n-(n-1))}=0$$  is this correct ?  If not why ?

Comment: It looks correct.

Comment: You did it alright

Comment: thanks but maybe i need to show that it is bounded from bellow and above.

Comment: +1 for showing your progress and thoughts about the problem! Too many people just post their question and expect to get an answer to paste into their homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct, but I imagine you're expected to show a bit more work to *justify* your assertion that
$$\lim \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(2n)\cdot(2n-1)\cdot(2n-2)\cdot ...\cdot(2n-(n-1))}=0$$
An easy way to do this is to bound this sequence of fractions with another, simpler one whose limit you know is 0.

Comment: This was a exam problem. I was thinking about showing that it is bounded. But i did not cause i could not find a supremum. Hopefully i get some points. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

$$0\leq\frac{n!}{(2n)!}\leq\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: this is comment, not an answer?

Comment: I see now, using the Sandwich Theorem  can show that the $lim$ is $0$. Thanks and +1

Comment: "Sandwich Theorem"

Answer (score 3):

Another hint based on using series may be that, if the series $$\sum_0^{\infty}u_n$$ is convergent so $u_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$ 0 \leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{(2n)!} \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!}{(n!)^2} = \lim_{k \to \infty, k = n!}\frac{k}{k^2} = \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{1}{k} = 0.$$

Comment: nice this is interesting

Answer (score 1):

If so addressing trivial rigorously I suggest using the notation produtory  to fatorial use the formula $n!=\prod_{k=1}^{n}$ .
\begin{align}
0\leq \frac{n!}{(2n)!}
=
&
\frac{\big(\prod_{k=1}^{n}k\big)}{\big(\prod_{k=1}^{2n}k\big)}
\\
=
&
\frac{\big(\prod_{k=1}^{n}k\big)}{\big(\prod_{k=n+1}^{2n}k\big)\big(\prod_{k=1}^{n}k\big)}
\\
=
&
\frac{1}{\big(\prod_{k=n+1}^{2n}k\big)}\frac{\big(\prod_{k=1}^{n}k\big)}{\big(\prod_{k=1}^{n}k\big)}
\\
=
&
\frac{1}{\big(\prod_{k=n+1}^{k=2n}k\big)}
\\
=
&
\frac{1}{2n\big(\prod_{k=n+1}^{2n-1}k\big)}
\\
=
&
\frac{1}{2n}\frac{1}{\big(\prod_{k=n+1}^{2n-1}k\big)}
\\
\leq
&
\frac{1}{2n}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice this is also a nice solution